# HTML & CSS: Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a grid system but I can't figure how to put the columns. To be more clear, I want the horizontal cards to be one under another without being divided. I tried changing the orded of the blocks but didn't seem to work at all. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header card-header-text card-header-warning">
              <div class="card-text">
                Welcome back, <b><?php echo $display_name; ?></b>!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Info</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras odio dui, sodales vitae fringilla quis, porta in nunc..
              </p>
              <footer class="blockquote-footer">Lorem</footer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header card-header-text card-header-danger">
                <div class="card-text">
                  <h4 class="card-title">News</h4>
                </div>
              </div> 
            <?php
            while($row = $stmtNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $row['date'] = date('j M', strtotime($row['date']));
            ?>
            <div class="card-body" style="max-height: 80px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">
                <?php echo $row['news']; ?>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <div class="card-text">
                    <small class="text-time"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></em></small>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-divider" style="margin: 15px;"></div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header card-header-text card-header-warning">
              <div class="card-text">
                Welcome back, <b><?php echo $display_name; ?></b>!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Info</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras odio dui, sodales vitae fringilla quis, porta in nunc...
              </p>
              <footer class="blockquote-footer">Lorem</footer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? change the order how? can you post a working snippet the reproduces the issue?

Comment: The screenshot shows exactly what you wrote. You are putting everything inside a div with class name "row" and the columns you specified as 8 and 4 are there. The third column is rendered after the one you defined as col-md-4. Start by separating what you want as rows and how many columns you wish those rows to hold. For example: to have all elements on top of each other, simply put them all inside a row, and give them col-lg-12 to occupy the whole width of the container. We need more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Zim What i want to accomplish is that I want to remove the space between the 2 cards with yellow header. I want them to be close. I will try to add a snippet right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but maybe this approach could help you:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          Level 1: .col-sm-9
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Level 2: .col-12
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Level 2: .col-12
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          Level 1: .col-sm-2
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              Level 2: .col-12 with defined or dynamic height
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It results in this grid:

[image]

It may not be the best idea, but it may be a first approach to solve your problem.

Comment: Your approach was actually the key. The result is as I wanted. Thank you!